# Pandas: Return a column name from a given value using a wildcard to match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, wildcard

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('transactions(1).csv')
userTransactionsDF = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Original Description', 'Amount', 'Category',
                                                             'Account Name'])
print(userTransactionsDF.head(1))

# output
#         Date Original Description  ...             Category             Account Name
# 0  4/14/2023            PETCO 304  ...  Pet Food & Supplies  DISCOVER IT CHROME CARD

data2 = pd.read_csv('recommended_categories.csv')
recommendedCategoriesDF = pd.DataFrame(data2)

print(recommendedCategoriesDF .head(1))

# output
#    Unnamed: 0  HOUSING TRANSPORT   FOOD  ... INCOME ENTERTAINMENT SERVICES Other
# 0           0      NaN     shell  qdoba  ...    NaN      nintendo      NaN   NaN
```

if `userTransactionsDF['Original Description'][0]` is a match to any of the values in `recommendedCategoriesDF`
with the '.+' wildcard on both sides of the value name in `recommendedCategoriesDF` , then I want to return the column name the value match with the wildcard was in

For example, if `['Original Description'][0]` outputs `'POS WD  Nintendo CA877180016   8'` then want it to match `'nintendo'` in recommendedCategoriesDF and return the column name `'ENTERTAINMENT'`

I have tried the below to cast the recommended categories dataframe into a dictionary and return the key if the the value was a match to any fo the values in the dictonary with a wildcard. I think I am way off base here...

```
        for j in userTransactionsDF['Original Description']:
            for p in userTransactionsDF['Amount']:
                print('original description = ' + j)
                #need to implement re to implement wildcard in below logical statement
                if (i for i in categories_dict if re.search('.+' + str(categories_dict[i]) + '.+', j)):
                    value = {i for i in categories_dict if re.search('.+' + str(categories_dict[i]) + '.+', j)}
                    print('value = ' + str(value))
                    categorized_Transactions.loc[len(categorized_Transactions)] = pandas.Series({value: p})
                else: categorized_Transactions.loc[len(categorized_Transactions)] = pandas.Series({'Other': p})
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use this :

```
userTransactionsDF = pd.read_csv("transactions(1).csv", header=None, skiprows=1,
                                  names=["Date", "Original Description", "Amount", "Category", "Account Name"])
​
recommendedCategoriesDF = pd.read_csv("recommended_categories.csv").drop(columns="Unnamed: 0")
​
dmap = recommendedCategoriesDF.stack().groupby(level=1).agg("|".join).to_dict()

matches = [next((col for (col, val) in dmap.items()
                 if re.search(fr"\b{val}\b", odesc, flags=re.I)), None)
           for odesc in userTransactionsDF["Original Description"]]
​
userTransactionsDF["Matched Category"] = matches #(optional) this puts the matches in a new column
```

Output :
​

```
print(userTransactionsDF)

        Date           Original Description  Category             Account Name Matched Category
0  4/14/2023  POS WD Nintendo CA877180016 8       NaN  DISCOVER IT CHROME CARD    ENTERTAINMENT

for odesc, mcat in zip(userTransactionsDF["Original Description"],
                       userTransactionsDF["Matched Category"]):
    print(f"original description = {odesc} / value = {mcat}")

#original description = POS WD Nintendo CA877180016 8 / value = ENTERTAINMENT
```

*Intermediates :*

```
print(dmap)

{'ENTERTAINMENT': 'nintendo', 'FOOD': 'qdoba', 'TRANSPORT': 'shell'}
```